# To access all the elements of a tuple inside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, tuples

I sent a tuple from python backend code to the frontend and tried to access all the elements of the tuple inside my javascript code.

Here, the "data" is a tuple containing an RGB color code, e.g (255,0,0) which I've passed to the frontend.
When I assigned this tuple ( here "data") to a variable in javascript, that variable say "x" takes only the last element of the tuple, but I need all the elements of tuple, how do I access all the elements of a tuple inside javascript?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x= {{data}};// access python variable inside html/javascript using double curly braces
  console.log(x);//gives the last element of tuple, e.g output: 0 if data=(255,0,0)
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of template engine to interpolate values into HTML? Tuples are not a thing that exists in Javascript. You need to do something that produces valid, meaningful Javascript (and interpolation may be a bad approach in the first place).

Comment: If what you're doing produces `var x= (255, 0, 0);` inside the script tags, then that's going to invoke the Javascript comma operator, which evaluates both operands, discards the left result, and produces the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot of things, thought of converting tuple into string and then do the slicing based on comma(",") but what I found out it that in javascript if you assign any variable a comma separated values enclosed inside round brackets("(",")") ,the variable takes the last element only.

```
<script>
var a=("apple","grapes","orange");
console.log(a);//output will be "orange"
</script>
```

So what I tried is :

```
<script>
var z= new Array{{data}};//"data" is tuple 
console.log(z[0],z[1],z[2]);//output:255,0,0 if data=(255,0,0)
</script>
```

And it worked!!